# on a button click calling ajax placeed sucess data in a div and toggle that div

Tags: jquery, ajax, toggle

```
<div class="toggle" id="response_18"></div>
<button class="btn btn-color btn-position shu" type="button" id="#response_18" value="18"></button>
```

N.B: i have three div and three button with different id.

using this jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".shu").click(function () {
//            var key = $(this).attr('value');

            var key = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "gv_calender.php",
                data: {key: key}
            }).done(function (data) {
                $(key).html(data);
            });

            $(key).toggle(1000);

            $(".toggle:visible").not(key).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**PROBLEM**: on first document load i have to click on the button twice. after that with single click i can load ajax data and toggle the respective div.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: You should not be using a # in your id="" HTML attribute. Instead, set the id to simple "response_18" then call it from jquery like this: $('#'+key) instead of $(key)

Comment: I also tried with what you suggest DanL. but problem still remain when first page load i have to click twice on the first button then its working as suppose to

Comment: Create a fiddle please https://jsfiddle.net Include any external libraries you are using and create an example of the issue for others to help you.

Comment: ok i will definitely add a fiddle

Comment: HI  DanL, this is my fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/k9hd6y58/ . on first page load div is slide out so fast. after that it's working fine.

Comment: i'm using ajax call and toggle with a same button. is there any way to make if div is showing then hide if not then show it.

Comment: today i added slight changes to my jquery script please have a look https://jsfiddle.net/vufje7af/